# cannot update Drupal core with drush

Tags: 7, drush

Why can't Drush find the Drupal core module?

```
root@hostname:/var/www/html/sites/example.org# drush pm-update core

...
Wysiwyg (wysiwyg)                        7.x-2.2         7.x-2.2         Up to date
core                                     Unknown         Unknown         Specified project not found
```

So then I tried:

```
root@hostname:/var/www/html/sites/example.org# drush -r /var/www/html -l example.org pm-update core
...
Wysiwyg (wysiwyg)                        7.x-2.2         7.x-2.2         Up to date
core                                     Unknown         Unknown         Specified project not found
```

I have used both these commands in the past to update other Drupal modules and it has always worked, until I have to update the Drupal core module.  Can Drush not handle this or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update core on its own try

```
drush pm-update drupal
```

A plain

```
drush pm-update
```

will update all modules, and then core.

Note that it doesn't backup .htaccess, robots.txt, or any other files that you may have modified.  I have gotten in the habit of doing a full `drush archive-dump` before core updates, and/or using [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) in combination with having everything under git control.

Comment: This worked!  Strange since the list of modules from drush does not list 'drupal' itself as a module.   Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

I installed drush 9.x
Now when I drush up I get:
 The pm-updatecode command was deprecated. Please see `composer outdated` and `composer update`. For security release notification, see `drush pm:security`.